# How to append text in every line of a file except for the first line

Tags: file, unix, append

I have a file say abc.txt with following data (real data has many records,say around 200)

> `Sno | Name`
>   `1 | Jack`
>   `2 | Jill`
>   `3 | June`

Now how do I append text to make my file look like this,

> `Sno | Name | Place`
>   `1 | Jack | Paris`
>   `2 | Jill | Paris`
>   `3 | June | Paris`

I tried replacing globally ,but first line should be appended with different text.So please help me out guys.

Comment: What tools do you use? Does bash or sed says something to you?

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
sed -e '2,$ s/$/|Paris/' < abc.txt
```

And including the header:

```
sed -e '1 s/$/|Place/' -e '2,$ s/$/|Paris/' < abc.txt
```

For the last line, you must have an extra blank line in the file.  So, delete all lines containing nothing but zero or more spaces:

```
sed -e '/^ *$/ d' -e '1 s/$/|Place/' -e '2,$ s/$/|Paris/' < abc.txt
```

Comment: but one small problem

Comment: | Paris is appearing as a separate last line.how to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1s/$/|Place/;/./!b;1!s/$/|Paris/' file
```

This appends `|Place` to the first line, ignores empty lines and all other lines appends `|Paris`.